# Separate levels of an outcome measure reported, but the means and SDs do not add up to the "total items," why?

Tags: meta-analysis

I am working on a meta-analysis that distinguishes achievement on two levels: content acquisition (e.g. knowledge and comprehension) and skills application (e.g. problem solving, etc.).

I came across a study that did ONE outcome measure, but broke the types of questions into three levels of understanding.  I will list the levels, means, and SD's in a moment, but ask my question first.

When I "add up" the Means and SDs (respectively) for each level, they do not add up to the "total items" Mean and SD, WHY??!!??  I ultimately want to combine the first two levels (knowledge and comprehension) and keep the application level separate.  I am only listing the intervention group's means and SDs, as I can figure out what to do for the comparison group once someone can help me.

1. Knowledge level:  Mean 4.14  SD (1.20)
2. Comprehension:   Mean 13.68  SD (2.36)
3. Application:     Mean  3.82  SD (1.08)
4. Total items:     Mean 21.57  SD (4.05)

What's the trick??  If I have to, I will just use the total items, as some of the studies in my meta only report one combined test score.  But, since this study broke it down, I would like to separate Knowledge/Comprehension from Application.

Thank you in advance for trying to help!

Comment: What study? Please give a complete reference in your question. Note that even if the "total items" was just a straight sum of those components, the standard deviations would not be expected to directly add.

Comment: The study citations is as follows:
Chang, C-Y. (2001). Comparing the impact of a problem-based computer-assisted instruction and the direct-interactive teaching method on student science achievement. Journal of Science Education and Technology, 10(2), 147-153. http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1009469014218

Comment: I get that the SDs will not necessarily add up, but the mean scores do not add up to the total items either.  In this study, the comparison group's means and (SDs) are as follows:
Knowledge level: 3.68 (1.23)
Comprehension:  12.92 (2.28)
Application:   3.87 (1.34)
Total (K,C,A)  20.53 (3.88)

Comment: So, if I want to add Knowledge and Comprehension together, so that I can use the mean score and SD's to compute Hedge's g, how do I do that to get an accurate effect size?  I am more concerned with computing the SD's correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the paper, the posttest scores in the table are "adjusted", but they don't clearly explain how they were adjusted; I'd guess they're adjusted for the covariates mentioned for the ANCOVA but I have no basis to claim that for sure; it seems there is only one mention of adjustment outside the table and it doesn't say more about it there either.

The adjustment will be what makes the means not quite (but nearly) add. There's no obvious way to know how to do it for the standard deviation without a clear statement of exactly what adjustment was made (and any data used in making it).

Comment: Thanks, Glen.  I will just go with what is in the paper and add the knowledge and comprehension means and standards deviations together.

Comment: If it weren't for the adjustment, the standard errors could likely be done, but not by adding them.